# O que faz o this() sozinho no construtor?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

No código:

```
public Livro(Autor autor) { 
        this();
        this.autor = autor;
    }
    public Livro() { 
        this.isbn = "000-00-00000-00-0";
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ele invoca o construtor que não recebe parâmetros, por exemplo na expressão `Livro l = new Livro(autor);` o que vai ocorrer é o seguinte:

1. `new Livro(autor)` vai invocar o construtor de livro que recebe um "autor" como parâmetetro, no caso `public Livro(Autor autor) {`
2. Internamente o construtor `public Livro(Autor autor) {` vai chamar this() que vai invocar o construtor Livro que não recebe nenhum parâmetro, no caso `public Livro() {`

Você poderia reescrever o código da seguinte forma equivalente:

```
public Livro(Autor autor) { 
    this.isbn = "000-00-00000-00-0"; // ao invés de invocar o construtor Livro() estamos ralizando o que o tal construtor faz.
    this.autor = autor;
}
public Livro() { 
    this.isbn = "000-00-00000-00-0";
}
```

Comment: Se o isbn fosse declarado no primeiro construtor o que recebe o autor como parametro, quando criar um novo objeto livro e sem autor ele não recebe o isbn, mas como null.

Answer (score 13):

`this` é uma referência para o objecto actual - o objecto de cujo método ou construtor está sendo chamado.

Quando usado dentro de um construtor serve para chamar outro construtor na mesma classe.

A sua classe Livro declara dois construtores:

```
public Livro(Autor autor)
```

e

```
public Livro()
```

No construtor `public Livro()` é inicializada o campo `isbn` que deve(suponho) ser inicializado qualquer que seja o construtor utilizado, daí a necessidade de este ser chamado pelo construtor `public Livro(Autor autor)`.

Outra razão comum para usar `this` é quando um parâmetro de um método ou construtor tem um "nome" igual a um campo da classe.
Repare no construtor `public Livro(Autor autor)`, cujo parâmetro é `autor`, foi necessário utilizar `this.autor = autor;` para diferenciar o parâmetro do campo.

Julgo que o código que postou seja apenas um exemplo, no entanto deixo aqui uma forma "mais correcta" de declarar os construtores:

```
public class Livro{

    private String isbn;
    private Autor autor; 

    public Livro(Autor autor, String isbn) { 
        this.autor = autor;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    //Talvez passar ""(empty) na vez de "000-00-00000-00-0"
    public Livro(Autor autor) { 
        this(autor, "000-00-00000-00-0");
    }

    //Talvez não se devesse criar um livro sem autor.
    //Ou talvez sim, se o autor for desconhecido.
    public Livro() { 
        //Em vez de null talvez fosse preferível criar um Autor "default"(desconhecido)
        this(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi o atributo `private Autor autor; `,  porque o primeiro método  recebe como parâmetro isso? Seria uma classe? E tem como passar classes como parâmetros?

Comment: @Jarwin Autor é uma classe, o atributo é necessário para guardar a instância(objecto) da classe Autor que é passada(o) no construtor.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro temos os princípios:

- De uma maneira curta, toda classe tem por default um construtor vazio.
- Por definição, `this` faz referência a própria classe.

Seguindo as definições, `this()` se faz referente ao construtor padrão de uma classe em Java =]