# Quando de fato preciso usar o operador this no Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

É que as vezes penso não haver a necessidade de uso do `this`, mas como apenas comecei a aprender Java, quero que alguém me responda quando é que realmente será necessário a utilização do operador `this`?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109845/o-que-faz-o-this-sozinho-no-construtor, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108957/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-do-uso-da-palavra-this, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118962/pra-que-serve-this-em-java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

4 situações:

- Referenciar uma variável de instância da classe de forma não ambígua

  É possível mas algumas pessoas recomendam evitar usar onde não é ambíguo. Então se uma variável de instância da classe não conflita com um nome de variável ou parâmetro do método, é comum evitar o uso. Ele é considerado como existente implicitamente.
- Usar como argumento de um método de outra classe que vai chamar quando deseja passar o próprio objeto atual

  Isso é útil quando você não tem ou não pode passar uma variável específica como argumento, a intenção é passar o próprio objeto, qual é o nome do objeto atual da classe? `this`. Mais abaixo explico porque essa é a variável.
- Acessar uma instância dentro de uma classe interna:

  ```
  public class Externa {
      private int x;
      public class Interna {
          private int x;
          public int exemplo() {
              return Externa.this.x;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Chamar um construtor do próprio objeto

  Há problemas em chamar construtores dentro dos construtores. Essa é uma forma de indicar que o que está chamando é o construtor. Há um tratamento especial. Essa chamada deve ser a primeira linha do construtor, não pode haver outro código antes. Mais em detalhes em [O que faz o this() sozinho no construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109845/101)

Note que o `this` nos dois primeiros casos funcionam praticamente como uma variável. O que muita gente não sabe é que o método é só uma função como outra qualquer que tem um parâmetro oculto chamado `this`. É apenas um açúcar sintático. Essa variável pode ser usada de formas variadas. Então:

```
class Tipo {
    private int variavel;
    public void exemplo(int x) {
        variavel = x;
    }
}
```

No fundo é isso:

```
class Tipo {
    private int variavel;
    public void exemplo(Tipo this, int x) {
        this.variavel = x;
    }
}
```

E esse é um exemplo da primeira utilização descrita. [Falo com mais detalhes em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108960/101) (é a mesma coisa).

A terceira forma é muito semelhante a esse caso.

A segunda forma seria:

```
class Tipo {
    public void exemplo(Tipo this, int x) { //já escrito sem o açúcar sintático
        metodoDeOutraClasse(this, x); //passa o objeto atual e o parâmetro x
    }
}
```

Obviamente que nesse caso a assinatura do método seria algo assim `metodoDeOutraClasse(Tipo objeto)`. Esse método muito provavelmente pertence a outra classe, não faria sentido na mesma.

No quarto caso o `this` funciona de forma especial pela linguagem. Ele usa essa convenção de nome para indicar que está chamando um construtor.

```
class Tipo {
    public Tipo(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public Tipo() {
        this(1);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/This.java).

Answer (score 7):

O único caso em que você **precisa** usar o `this` é quando tem uma variável de escopo (ou parâmetro) com o mesmo nome de um atributo (ou variável de classe) e precisa diferenciá-los.

Um exemplo comum

```
public class Cliente {
    private String nome;

    public void setNome(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;

        //perceba que nome se refere ao parâmetro e this.nome se refere ao atributo
    }
}
```

Fora isso, você nunca será "obrigado" a usá-lo. Isso fica um sujeito ao estilo que cada você usa para codificar.

Answer (score 3):

Explicando de uma maneira menos formal, o `this` se refere ao objeto atual. Por exemplo: você tem um objeto bola com uma propriedade cor, pode acessar a propriedade cor com `this.cor`

Já o método `this()` com ou sem parâmetros se refere ao construtor da sua classe. Este só pode ser usado dentro de outro construtor.

Exemplo retirado desse [site](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/this.php).

> Se criarmos um método que receba um argumento chamado ligado que
>   queremos atribuir para o atributo da classe, que também se chama
>   ligado, devemos diferenciar ambos mostrando a quem cada um pertence.
>   Como `this` se refere ao contexto empregado, então o usamos para
>   identificar que ligado será o atributo da classe e ligado sem o `this`
>   se refere ao parâmetro do método. O que resultaria nisto:
>
> ```
> public class TV {
>     //atributos
>     int tamanho;
>     int canal;
>     boolean ligada;
>
>     // método contrutor com parâmetro
>     TV(boolean ligada) {
>         this.ligada = ligada;
>         /**
>          * Onde this.ligada é o atributo
>          * e ligada é o valor do parâmetro
>          */
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma fácil de entender é:

Quando você tem duas variáveis em escopos diferentes: uma local (em um método) e outra global(na classe). Quando você precisa referenciar a global você usa o this, ex: `this.var`.

O pessoal deu um bom exemplo com os métodos. 
Usamos bastante nos métodos getters e setters.