# Como criar um método estático em uma classe pública?

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Gostaria de criar um método estático em uma classe pública com um `ToastController` para que eu possa acessar esse método em várias classes. Tentei fazer desta forma abaixo mas não funcionou:

```
export class Utils {

  constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController) {    
  }  

  static showToast(message, pos) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ /* <---- erro nessa linha */
      message: message,
      duration: 3000,
      position: pos
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

    toast.present();
  }
}
```

Basicamente o propósito reutilizar código. Como posso criar um método estático em uma classe publica?

Comment: Obrigado funcionou para mim!!!!!!!! https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/utils.ts

Comment: Não adicione "obrigado" como resposta. Quando tiver [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes, você poderá [votar a favor de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que considerar úteis. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/194676)

Answer (score 1):

A criação do método está ok, tanto que não dá erro nisso. O que está errado é acessar `this` em um método estático. Se o método é estático, ele pertence à classe e não a uma instância. Mesmo que fosse acessar, qual `this` deveria acessar?

Alternativamente você pode enviar o objeto para o método, aí você o acessa explicitamente como parâmetro. Você não poderá acessar os membros privados do objeto desta forma, mas os públicos ok. Se estiver acessando só os públicos pode fazer:

```
export class Utils {
    constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController) {}  

    static showToast(object, message, pos) {
        let toast = object.toastCtrl.create({
            message: message,
            duration: 3000,
            position: pos
        });
      toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
      });
      toast.present();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/StaticMethod.ts).

Aí chamará `Utils.showToast(objeto, "menssagem", 10);`.

Mas note que isso não parece TS (apesar de ser), faltam os tipos dos parâmetros. Eu não vou arriscar colocar neles porque não tenho certeza de quais seriam.

Nem sei se esta seria a melhor solução, mas não tenho contexto.

Comment: No `tsconfig.json` é possível configurar a variável `noImplicitAny` para `false`, nesse caso qualquer variável sem um tipo explícito automaticamente é proposto o tipo implicitamente como `any`, ou seja, dependendo do `tsconfig.json` esse código é um TS válido.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura sim, mas se vai usar TS, não deveria fazer isso, o principal motivo do TS é usar a tipagem.

Comment: concordo plenamente com isto, eu mesmo configuro a flag sempre para `true`, mas só repassei para complementar a parte do texto `não parece TS`, inclusive acho que seria interessante na resposta falar sobre a flag e incentivar o uso dela no código proposto

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Só tirei a ambiguidade, fica o seu comentário como complemento já que isso não faz parte do problema.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, se isso não for TS eu não sei o que é exatamente TS. Criei um projeto padrão do com cordova+ionic2+angular2  e me gerou o arquivo .ts neste mesmo formato, porém com o `import` desta forma `import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';` .. não quis acrescentar para deixar mais objetivo. Bom, tentei o que você fez, porém não funcionou aqui ainda. Minha pergunta agora pode parecer óbvia, mas não consegui usar. Esse parâmetro objeto, o que devo passar nele em outra classe por exemplo?

Comment: @AckLay não sei, não tenho informações suficientes para dizer, mas certamente é alguma coisa que tem `toastCtrl`, talvez tenha que ser um tipo `ToastController`. Se tivesse a tipagem, já seria óbvio. Esse parâmetro `object` é justamente o que devria ser o `this`, eu não sei o que deveria ser, nada nessa classe indica isso. Entenda que o `this` é só uma parâmetro oculto do método com o objeto que está sendo manipulado. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154195/101. Eu já achei estranho esse construtor em uma classe chamada `Utils` e que recebe um `ToastController`.

Comment: @bigown cara, eu ainda estou estudando a documentação, então ainda levo alguns tombos. Para falar a verdade, eu resolvi o meu problema sem  declarar o método como estático, ainda estou estudando se fiz da maneira correta. Usei o `@Injectable()` na minha classe Utils, ai declarei dentro do `@Component` em outra classe como providers desta forma: `providers: [Utils]`... para fins de minha necessidade, funcionou bem, mas não tenho certeza se é a maneira correta fazer. O detalhe é que a classe não precisou estar como estática. Vou fazer mais alguns testes e te dou um retorno.

Comment: @AckLay alguma coisa me dizia que esse método não era necessário mesmo. Esses detalhes específicos eu não sei. Eu respondi sobre o porquê de estar dando erro naquela linha e como resolver, até onde eu podia responder com o que foi postado.

Comment: @bigown o que eu fiz foi isso que [está no github](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/utils.ts)  que ainda estou estudando.

Comment: @AckLay é, assim funciona, eu não sei o que é esse `Injectable` então não posso falar nada, espero que isso faça a classe ter sentido, pra mim ela é esquisita na forma que está, mas deve ter um motivo que eu desconheço. Não conheço Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Como você tem uma dependecia de `ToastController`, que é um serviço Ionic disponivel para ser injectado, o correto seria você criar outro serviço para fazer sua manipulação de mensagens.

Para realizar isso você deve decorar sua `class` com [`@Injectable()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable):

```
@Injectable()
export class Utils {
   //...
}
```

E adiciona-la no `provider` de seu `modulo` ou de sua `class` que irá utiliza-lo:

```
@Component({

    // ...

    // adiciona a declaração do provider aqui para que o angular (DI) saiba em qual escopo a instancia do serviço deve ser compartilhada
    // isso pode ser declarado também em modulo, onde todo o modulo irá compartilha a mesma instancia da classe injetada
    providers: [
      Utils
      ]
})
export class AppComponent {

   constructor(public utils: Utils){

   }
    // ...
}
```

**Exemplo:**

[<kbd>Exemplo funcional (Sem **Ionic** e por consequência sem `ToastController`, utilizando um `alert` em seu lugar).</kbd>](https://embed.plnkr.co/gRi5o4nGelSPMuwXYYas/?show=app%2Fapp.component.ts&show=preview)