# Como faço para que os métodos recebam os parâmetros x e y?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Quando eu solicito os valores de `x` e `y`, eu quero fazer com que as operações dos métodos recebam os valores digitados pelo usuário. O que fazer?

```
public class Calculadora {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

protected double x;
protected double y;
protected double soma;
protected double subt;
protected double mult;
protected double divs;


void setValores(){
    System.out.println("Informe dois valores: ");
    this.x = sc.nextDouble();
    this.y = sc.nextDouble();
}
void setSoma(double x, double y){
    this.soma = x + y;
}
double getSoma(){
    return soma;
}
void setSubt(double x, double y){
    this.subt = x-y;
}
double getSubt(){
    return subt;
}
void setMult(double x, double y){
    this.mult = x*y;
}
double getMult(){
    return mult;
}
void setDivs(double x, double y){
    this.divs = x/y;
}
double getDivs(){
    return divs;
}


void showValor(){
    System.out.println("soma: " + this.soma);
}
}
```

Comment: Você entende o quê a linha `this.x = ...` e `this.y = ...` faz? Entende o que `this.x` e `this.y` são?

Comment: Acredito que recebem os valores digitados, já que está sendo usado Scanner para ler os valores informados.

Comment: Foi você que escreveu o código? Sabe o que são atributos de instância?

Comment: Foi eu, isso é um exercício. Atributos são as características que são dadas ao objeto que for instanciado de uma classe. Nesse caso aí, os atributos são x, y, soma, subt, mult e divs...

Comment: Precisa dizer qual é o objetivo geral do problema e porque este código não tem nem pé nem cabeça. De acordo com o objetivo seria escrito de uma forma ou de outra.

Comment: Entendi. Esta classe deve ser abstrata e implementar as operações básicas (soma, subtração, divisão e multiplicação)... até aí sei que tem que ser 'public abstract class'. então o objetivo é fazer o uso dessa classe no main, solicitando os valores ao usuário através da classe Scanner e passando para os métodos dos objetos gerados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que seja isto que deseja:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informe dois valores: ");
        Calculadora calc = new Calculadora(sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble());
        System.out.println(calc.soma());
        System.out.println(calc.subtracao());
        System.out.println(calc.multiplicacao());
        System.out.println(calc.divisao());
    }
}

class Calculadora {
    protected double x;
    protected double y;

    Calculadora(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    double soma() {
        return x + y;
    }
    double subtracao() {
        return x - y;
    }
    double multiplicacao() {
        return x * y;
    }
    double divisao() {
        return x / y;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CtyiIm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/salfggcg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Calculator.java).

Não fiz abstrata para facilitar o teste, mas isso não muda a essência. Tenho minhas dúvidas se precisa disso. Na verdade vejo pouca utilidade para esta classe.

Tirei o pedido de digitação da classe porque são responsabilidades diferentes. Quem cuida da interação com o usuário não deve ser a classe de negócio. Usei um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) que é o correto a se fazer.

Se já tem o dado não precisa ficar passando para os métodos como argumento. Todo método que não é estático já tem um parâmetro que é o `this`, então os valores do objeto já são acessíveis em todos os métodos dele. E [o `this` nem precisa ser digitado quando o nome não é ambíguo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154186/101).

Simplifiquei bastante fazendo tudo o que foi descrito na pergunta. E dei nomes melhores e formatação mais limpa.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Tava com dúvida em como usar o Scanner para atribuir valores a x e y.