# Atualizar fragmento com ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-adapter

Pretendo fazer "refresh" a um fragmento (fragment30.java) que apresenta os registos de uma tabela SQlite após a eliminação de um destes registos .

Os registos são apresentados recorrendo a uma *ListView* associada a um *Adapter*  (MyAdapter.java) e penso que a dificuldade é que a rotina de eliminação está neste ficheiro ...

Já tentei de tudo com um total insucesso ...

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<programas> {

private DataBase dataBase;
private SQLiteDatabase conn;

// TABELA programas

private programas[] mInfos;

public MyAdapter(Context context, programas[] infos) {
    super(context, 0 ,infos);
    mInfos = infos;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list,null);


    // ligação das TextView a este componente

    TextView titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    TextView descricao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    final programas in = getItem(position);


    // preenchimento das TextView

    titulo.setText(in.getTitulo());
    descricao.setText(in.getCanal()+"/"+in.getDia()+":"+in.getHora());

    titulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder AlertaRes = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            AlertaRes.setTitle("CONFIRMA ELIMINAÇÃO ?");
            AlertaRes.setMessage(in.getTitulo());
            AlertaRes.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

            AlertaRes.setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dataBase = new DataBase(getContext());
                    conn = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

                    String whereClause = "titulo='"+ in.getTitulo() +"'";

                    conn.delete("programas",whereClause,null);
                    conn.close();



                    // CÓDIGO PARA FAZER O REFRESH 

                }
            });

            AlertaRes.setNegativeButton("NÃO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Registo Não Gravado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            AlertaRes.show();



        }

    });


    return convertView;
}
```

}

**Fragment30.java**

```
public class Fragment30 extends Fragment {

private DataBase dataBase;
private SQLiteDatabase conn;
private Context mContext;


@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater li, ViewGroup vg, Bundle b) {

    mContext = getActivity();

    View rootView = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment30, vg, false);

    ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_items);


    dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
    conn = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] colunas = new String[]{"titulo", "tipo", "canal","dia","hora"};

    Cursor cursor = conn.query("programas", colunas, null, null, null, null, "titulo ASC");


    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        int conta = 0;

        programas[] values = new programas[cursor.getCount()];

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {

            conta++;
            values[conta-1] = new programas(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        MyAdapter adapter2 = new MyAdapter(mContext,values);
        list.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }else{

        programas[] values = new programas[1];
        values[0] = new programas("Sem registos"," "," "," "," ");

        MyAdapter adapter2 = new MyAdapter(mContext,values);

        list.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

}

**programas.java**

```
public class programas {

private String titulo;
private String tipo;
private String canal;
private String dia;
private String hora;
private long id;

public programas (String titulo, String tipo,String canal,String dia,String hora){

    this.titulo=titulo;
    this.tipo=tipo;
    this.canal=canal;
    this.dia=dia;
    this.hora=hora;

}


public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}
public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
public String getCanal() {
    return canal;
}
public void setCanal(String canal) {
    this.canal = canal;
}
public String getDia() {
    return dia;
}
public void setDia(String dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}
public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Após quaisquer alterações nos dados do seu adapter, você deve chamar o método [`notifyDatasetChanged`](http://voc%C3%AA%20deve%20notificar%20o%20adaptador%20de%20que%20houve%20uma%20mudan%C3%A7a%20nos%20dados.%20Isso%20pode%20ser%20feito%20com%20o%20m%C3%A9todo%20notifyDatasetChanged.), que irá atualizar a sua ListView de acordo com as mudanças. Caso isso não seja suficiente para atualizar os dados, você também pode executar a query novamente e substituir o adaptador (`ListView.setAdapter(...)`).

Contudo, sugiro que repense sua implementação utilizando um [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter), que nada mais é do que um adapter que lê os dados diretamente do cursor - e não de um array como você está fazendo. Indico [esse tutorial do Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) (em inglês) sobre o tema.

Considere também a possibilidade de utilizar o padrão `ViewHolder` para otimizar o desempenho da sua lista. Indico [este artigo](https://blog.alura.com.br/utilizando-o-padrao-viewholder/) sobre como fazê-lo.

Comment: Sim, a solução poderá ser o método "notifyDatasetChanged" , no entanto mesmo assim existe a dificuldade de accioná-lo dentro do próprio adapter : a rotina de eliminação está dentro desta classe ... Quanto a executar a query novamente como a activity (fragmento) vai ter conhecimento da eliminação ? Relativamente às sugestões CursorAdapter e ViewHolder, agradeço muito e vou estudar o assunto

Comment: Tente `MyAdapter.this.notifyDatasetChanged()`. Caso tenha dúvidas em entender o uso do `this`, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154195/7499).

Comment: No caso da activity/fragmento ter "conhecimento" (acredito que o melhor termo seria "ser notificada") sobre a atualização dos dados seria necessário utilizar um `callback`. Recomendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311322/7499) para estudar sobre o assunto.